# Negative feedback gain sensitivity

Tags: control-system, negative-feedback, sensitivity

What happens to the gain sensitivity of negative feedback system due to fractional change in open loop gain  when feedback gain His about 0.01-0.05.

Here's my work:

[image]

Comment: That's a good question.  What do you think about it?

Comment: According to me it should decrease by 1/(1+AB)...but I am not sure

Comment: Show your work.  It's pretty clear this is a homework or a test question.

Comment: Well, have you seen it?

Comment: Where's beta and what is T?

Comment: T is the transfer function and H=B= negetive feedback gain. H is generally 0.01-0.05 in operational amplifier